# Getting the 140 Twitter character limit to reset itself after url shorten

Tags: twitter

The example original tweet

> Getting Started with Phidgets and ActionScript 3 http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2010/07/26/getting-started-with-phidgets-and-actionscript/

0 Characters left.

The modified tweet after submittal

> Getting Started with Phidgets and ActionScript 3 http://bit.ly/xxxxxx

71 characters left.

How can I get the Twitter web application to understand that I still have usable characters once they shorten the url ?

*Without having to use third parties such as Tweetie or Hootsuite.*

<sub>(I am not posting URL shortened links so I have put a place holder, here is the original http://twitter.com/phwd/status/19671211151)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that I know to get around it is to shorten the URL yourself BEFORE you try to post an update via the web.

That is the process I do.

Comment: That's a good process. I prefer to have shortened URLs associated with my bit.ly account rather than with Twitter's so I can manage them all in one place.

Comment: This is what I do currently but honestly *some* url shorteners affect page rank. It also does not matter to me who clicked my link to someone else's website, not my kind of fancy to *manage* shortened links, to me it is about getting it within that 140 limit. The best process IMHO is some userscript that is able to shorten the link in a similar manner to how Hootsuite does it .

Comment: Perhaps using Google's URL shortener will allay your fears about PageRank. There's a bookmarklet for it out there if you don't want to use the Google toolbar.

Comment: @Al Sweet! I will switch to Google then.

Answer (score 1):

Three years later, Twitter is smart enough to know the length of the short URL despite still having the original URL in the Tweet box. Keep in mind, this is using Twitter's URL shortening service which I believe is [`t.co`](https://t.co/).

I've just tested it on the following applications:

#### Twitter website

[image: Twitter website screenshot]

#### Twitter app for Windows 8

[image: Twitter app for Windows 8 screenshot]

#### Twitter for BlackBerry 6

#### Twitter on iOS

#### iOS's native Twitter integration

I can also bet that Twitter on Android, Windows Phone, and BlackBerry 10 has the same functionality.